# Vaadin 24: TinyMCE for Flow (Team Parttio version) Initial Render Blank

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I'm using the TinyMCE editor for Vaadin Flow by Team Parttio (https://vaadin.com/directory/component/tinymce-for-flow) with Vaadin 24.1.3 and Version 4.0.5 of the TinyMCE Editor.

**This component is EXCELLENT - except for one thing:** I'm using it on an edit form with a grid. The first time the edit form is shown from a click on the grid, the TinyMCE editor is blank. Every other grid click to show the edit form - the editor is properly populated. When you click another form (from the side navigation) and come back to the grid and click the edit button - same thing happens - the editor is blank. Subsequent editing works perfectly.

**Here's what I've tried:**

- I've checked the bindings - and all is good - the component is
  getting the proper data;
- I tried having only the editor object on the
  edit form - same problem;
- I tried putting it in a dialog - same
  problem;
- Changed the order of when the binding happens compared with
  the showing of the edit form - same problem;
- When the component is
  visible (e.g. not hidden at the start) and an edit click from the
  grid happens - it renders correctly every time;

I'm sure it's something simple... I'm at a loss. If anyone can help me solve this issue - it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have no problems using it with Vaadin 24. Try to update to 24.1.14

Comment: Hi Simon- thanks very much for your suggestion. I've updated to 24.1.14 and am having the same issue. Any other suggestions on how I can debug this?

Comment: Can you share your code or create a minimal reproducible example? Because as I said I use it in many projects without any issue.

Comment: Hi Simon. The code is pretty complex and would be hard to reproduce... I'm happy to share the underlying code. What's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to not use "setvisible" on the form, but to use CSS classes (form.addClass("xyz")) to then set the visibility and display of the form. That way they are rendered correctly (and appear in the DOM if you inspect the page) but are hidden from the user.

Comment: For more information reference this similar question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17078864/forcing-vaadin-component-to-occupy-its-space-in-invisible-state